# Can positrons flow through matter or antimater or both?

Tags: electricity, antimatter

Now, I know that a flow of positrons can constitute electricity. But my question is whether positrons can flow through matter conductors like copper or only antimatter conductors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no difference between the flow of electrons or positrons in terms of a resulting current. In other words, there is no distinction between 'positive' and 'negative' electricity. If the entire universe were to be comprised of antimatter as opposed to matter, we would not notice a difference in the way our universe is. That is, if our universe were one where the standard model consisted of all particles exactly the same and opposite charge, everything would be the same, and positrons would flow through anticopper.

But when we consider antimatter within in our matter dominated universe, it is essentially restricted to interaction with other antimatter, as positrons and electrons will annihilate one another. As all elements are ultimately comprised of particles within the standard model, positrons could not just flow through what we know as copper, as the positrons would interact with the electrons in the copper and annihilate.

Comment: Thanks!But will it annihilate the electrons in the atom or only free electrons?